# Javafx Scrollpane is being shown even when it's not needed

Tags: javafx

I have this Javafx element

```
        HBox dosWrap = new HBox();
        dosWrap.setMinHeight(400);
        dosWrap.setMaxHeight(452);
        dosWrap.setMinWidth(900);

        VBox todo = new VBox();
        todo.setMinWidth(300);
        todo.setMinHeight(400);

        ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
        sp.setContent(todo);
        sp.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        sp.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);

        dosWrap.getChildren().add(sp);
```

The scroller is being shown and works,but my problem is that scroller is being shown even when it's not needed.How do i stop that?

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: You can try to not set it at all that works for my application it doesn't show unless there enough elements